# How to change the port of a running Boost::ASIO udp socket

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-asio

The Boost ASIO library provides a `port()` get/set method for a socket `local_endpoint`, but when I try to switch to a different port while the work queue is running, calling `socket.local_endpoint().port(1234)` call does not change the port. Does anyone have experience with this?

Based on an option received over TFTP, I need to switch the port over which the server and client are communicating.

Comment: Does `socket.local_endpoint().port(1234)` even compile at all? I'm pretty sure it shouldn't... In any case, you will most likely just have to close the socket and open a new one on the new port.

Answer (score 0):

To answer why

> socket.local_endpoint().port(1234) call does not change the port.

as far as I know, the `basic_socket` class `*_endpoint()` implementations return a copy of `endpoint_type` object, not a reference, so the change you are trying to make, won't affect the `socket` object.

Comment: This question is about how to change the port, not why.

Comment: This post has two parts, one is a primary question which is in the tittle and the other one is a why question which is in the description (looks like you didn't read the post completely), But be that as it may, I explicitly stated, my answer is about addressing the second part (so, now it is clear you haven't read the answer too) .....

Comment: This answer explains why (which is important too) but doesn't answer the title which is "how" you do it